# Get tweets for a user in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter, spring-social

How to get tweets for a user in spring mvc just like how twitter widget works

I dont want to create application as mentioning in http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/. instead need to read without connecting

Want to read the top tweets for the specified user and need to display in JSP in custom format. Is there any way in spring mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using version 1.0.5 of spring-social-twitter - TwitterTemplate will allow a few simple operations that do not require authorization, such as searching. You need to create an instance of TwitterTemplate without passing in any oauth parameters.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/apis.html